# How to redirect two domains to the same subfolder using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

If you want redirect two separate domains to the same subfolder using .htaccess, you can use the code below by changing domains and folders to match your situation.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

# Redirect PuistoSahlynSM.fi

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?puistosahlynsm\.fi
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !puisto/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ puisto/$1 [L]

# Redirect PuistoSählynSM.fi

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xn--puistoshlynsm-hfb\.fi
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !puisto/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ puisto/$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?puistos(a|ä)hlynsm\.fi` would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find the Punycode name of your internationalized domain name.

[Wikipedia article on Internationalized Domain Names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)

[IDNA converter from WP article](http://idna-converter.com/)